How the method of interpolate in pytorch works?
I'm using torch.nn.functional.interpolate recently. But I don't know how it works.
for example, I give an input y as follows:
>>> y
tensor([[[[ 1.9218, -0.1529, -0.4899, -0.0768],
          [-1.5783,  0.0260, -1.0002,  0.2541],
          [-0.2185, -0.6166,  0.7606,  0.2055],
          [ 1.6895, -0.0580,  0.0401,  0.7642]]]])
>>> torch.nn.functional.interpolate(y,size=(2,2),mode="bilinear", align_corners=True, antialias=True)
tensor([[[[-0.1076,  0.0479],
          [ 0.3141,  0.4787]]]])

My question is how the values calculate in the result? i.e. the calculate process for getting -0.1076, 0.0479, 0.3141, 0.4787 in the result tensor.
Could someone show me the calculate process for getting -0.1076, 0.0479, 0.3141, 0.4787 in the result tensor.
